# Upload files from browser to S3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-s3

I have a pre signed url that allows you to PUT documents objects into S3.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjectPreSignedURLDotNetSDK.html

How do I put a file from the browser to S3 using javascript?  I am using angular, but I am open to using any javascript library.

I believe I could POST to my server, and then PUT the object on the amazon server, but I would prefer to do it from the browser.

I have changed the CORS settings on S3 to allow PUTs.

I was planning to use angular file upload, but it is hard coded to POST not PUT.
https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload

Comment: An upload library I maintain, [Fine Uploader](http://fineuploader.com) natively handles uploads directly to S3 in all browsers, including IE7. It also supports chunking, auto-resume, retry, and a bunch of other features.  It does most of the heavy lifting for you in this regard, while other libraries do not.  A live demo of the upload-to-s3 function can be found on the page I just linked to.

Comment: Actually for https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload and you can specify the method: 'PUT' in upload params. It should work with S3 if you follow the issues some people are using it for S3 and the issues has resolved in version 1.1.1. You can follow the issues here: https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload/pull/26, https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload/issues/23, https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload/issues/25

Comment: The new version also supports drop file and upload progress.

Comment: @danial do you know if github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload supports chunking to s3?

Comment: I don't think amazon s3 supports chunk upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon has a guide ([here](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434)) that describes how to POST-upload a file into your S3 bucket.  It relies on an input <form> signed with your AWS private key.  You can specify restrictions on the target directory, as well as file-size restrictions.

It's a bit annoying to use, because you have to duplicate most of the fields in both the <form> and the signed policy, but it seems to work.

After the POST, S3 will redirect the browser to a URL you specify in the form (with parameters specifying the name of the uploaded file, etc.).  This isn't ideal for Angular web sites, which tend to be "applications" rather than a set of discrete pages, but you could probably work with it.

On my Angular site, I did the POST in Javascript using $http.post() and passed all the appropriate form data.  Unfortunately, I was always getting "cancelled" errors, even though the uploads were actually successful.  In my case, I just double-checked by downloading the file with $http.get() and comparing it to the original data... but this was only a viable solution because my files were only a couple of KB.

Comment: this seems like a reasonable route to go.  do you have any code samples?  are you using a file upload javascript library?